# how to conditionnally copy an above case in a column of a dataframe using nested np.where statement

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, where-clause, algorithmic-trading

I have 3 columns in my Dataframe df : In the 3rd column 'Entry Price Repeat', i would like to copy the above case of the same column IF the case of the 2nd column 'Position' is 1 for the same raw and the raw above. Else, i want to copy the case of the 1st column 'Adj Close' in the column 'Entry Price Repeat'. This behavior is very simple to do in XLS using 3 "nested if" and the expected result is in the picture below
[Dataframe][1]  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DzfQ.png

When doing it in Python with the below code (using 2 nested np.where, it isn't working, the result is in the below picture and i don't understand why. Can someone help and correct my code ? (the copy stops after 2 iterations of 'position'=1)

```
df2['Entry Price Repeat'] = df2['Adj Close']
df2['Entry Price Repeat'] = np.where(df2['Position'].shift(1) == 1, 
                                     np.where(df2['Position'] == 1,
                                              df2['Entry Price Repeat'].shift(1),
                                              -df2['Adj Close']
                                              )
                                    ,df2['Adj Close'])
```

[Result of the code above][1]  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxoU7.png

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly the code below should do it. First you populate the 'Entry Price Repeat' with the current or previous row in that 'Position' is equal to 0. Once you have done that, you just need to use pandas fillna method with front fill.

```
df2['Entry Price Repeat'] = df2['Adj Close']
df2['Entry Price Repeat'] = df2[(df2["Position"] == 0) | (df2["Position"].shift(1) == 0)]['Adj Close']
df2.fillna(method='ffill')
```

With the code below you should get the same result of your desired output.